# Translation invariant ultrafilters?

Tags: set-theory, filters, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Is there an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{U}-n = \mathcal{U}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Here, $$\mathcal{U}-n = \{ A - n: A \in \mathcal{U} \}$$ and $$A - n = \{ m \in \mathbb{N}: m+n \in A \}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $E$ and $O$ be the set of even and odd naturals respectively, and note that $E-1=O$ and $O-1=E$. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter, either $E\in\mathcal{U}$ and $O\not\in\mathcal{U}$ or $E\not\in\mathcal{U}$ and $O\in\mathcal{U}$. Either way, there is an $X\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $X-1\not\in\mathcal{U}$, so $\mathcal{U}\not=\mathcal{U}-1$.

By a similar argument (consider "alternating blocks of size $n$") we get $\mathcal{U}\not=\mathcal{U}-n$ for every ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ and every nonzero $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So in fact we can never have the equality in the OP happen for even a single (nonzero) natural number.

Comment: I seem to recall that the term "translation invariant ultrafilter" or something like that (almost translation invariant?) is an obsolete name for what is now called an idempotent ultrafilter, i.e., an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\mathbb N$ with the property that $$A\in\mathcal U\implies\{n:A-n\in\mathcal U\}\in\mathcal U.$$ Idempotent ultrafilters do exist (ZFC) and if $\mathcal U$ is one then $E\in\mathcal U$.

Comment: @bof Yes, but such an ultrafilter is a very different thing than the ultrafilters asked for in the OP.